# XPath: match 'foo' descendants of 'bar', but not if 'quux' is in between

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

In XPath (1.0 only, please) is it possible to find all 'foo' descendants of 'bar' for which there is no 'quux' at any level *in between*? That is, for instance, these 'foo's should match:

```
<bar><foo/></bar>
<bar><a><foo/></a></bar>
<bar><a><b><c><d><e><f><g><foo/></g></f></e></d></c></b></a></bar>
```

but these should not:

```
<bar><quux><foo/></quux></bar>
<bar><a><quux><foo/></quux></a></bar>
<bar><quux><a><foo/></a></quux></bar>
<bar><a><quux><b><foo/></b></quux></a></bar>
```

Instances of `quux` that are either above `bar` or below `foo` should *not* prevent a match, i.e. these 'foo's *should* match:

```
<bar><foo><quux/></foo></bar>
<quux><bar><foo/></bar></quux>
```

`bar/not(quux)/foo` doesn't work because it only accepts a three-level structure.  Anything with `//` in it will let a quux slip through at that point.  `bar//foo[not(ancestor::quux)]` *almost* works, but fails when a quux is an ancestor of bar.

Comment: [Select descendant elements that are not contained in another type of element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32272125) looks similar, although in that case they're already in the `bar` node. [xpath: get nodes that do not have an X ancestor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2177017) might work: `./bar//foo[not(ancestor::quux)]`?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan That looks like it will work in the concrete situation I am concerned with, because `bar` happens to be the root element.  However, it fails to solve the problem as stated, with the counterexample `<quux><bar><foo/></bar></quux>`, which I will add to the question.

Comment: Dang, I almost had it with `//foo[ancestor::bar[not(descendant::quux)]]` but then you had to allow `quux` inside of `foo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of expressing what you want is that the number of `quux` ancestors of a `foo` is the same as the number of `quux` ancestors of that `foo`s `bar` ancestor, so that all the `quux`s are ancestors of both the `bar` and the `foo`.

The following expression will select such `foo`s:

```
//bar//foo[count(./ancestor::quux) = count(./ancestor::bar/ancestor::quux)]
```