# What is the XPath expression for <span>s not inside <div>s?

Tags: html, xpath

I'm trying to find ONLY the `<span>` tags OUTSIDE `div` tags.  Sample HTML:

```html
<span>find me</span>
<span>find me</span>
<div>
    <span>don't find me</span>
</div>
```

What I've tried is the following, but I'm getting all `<span>`'s

```xml
//*[not(self::div)]/span
```

Comment: Your expression `//*[not(self::div)]/span` should work, at least for your particular example. I suspect there's something else going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
//span[not(ancestor::div)]
```

Literally, this will match all nodes with `span` tag name who have no ancestor with tag name `div`.
Credits to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177017/xpath-get-nodes-that-do-not-have-an-x-ancestor/2177078)

Comment: Your option seem to be more generic but I can hardly imagine HTML-doc with the span node that doesn't have at least one div ancestor

Comment: I'm agree with you, but this is what this question about, as I understand it. In case author asked for expression to find span with no direct parent div - I will add it too, it is simple.

Comment: It's true.  It's a simplified example that's nothing like what I'm trying to do real-world.  I was just trying to get across that it was an HTML tag and I was trying to exclude its existence inside another HTML tag.  In reality it's some funky non-standard HTML but I just needed the XPath expression and didn't want to muddy the waters.

Answer (score 1):

Try below one to get required output

```
//span[not(parent::div)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I actually needed `ancestor` and not `parent`, but I didn't make my example clear enough.